# mySQL: SELECT with reference to another table w/o JOIN

Tags: mysql, select, join, where-clause, placeholder

In MS Access I had a query like

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1, t2
WHERE (((t1.c1) Like t2.c1));
```

In t1.c1 I had e. g.

```
"head of marketing"
"head of sales"
"software developer"
...
```

In t2.c1 I had e. g.

```
" 'asterisk' head of 'asterisk' " (with "*" as placeholders in front and after the search term).
```

When I ran the query I got

```
"head of marketing"
"head of sales"
```

Thus it worked fine.

I switched from MS Access to mySQL. There the statement doesn't return a result - only exact matches.

How do I reproduce the SQL statement in native mySQL?

Server Version: 5.6.32-78.1-log
Protokoll-Version: 10

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you mean with the asterisks. Seems like you may be fighting the Markdown formatting and compensating for that? To format code and avoid accidentally getting bold text, highlight code blocks or inline and use the `{}` editor toolbar button or `ctrl-k`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asterisks in Access seem to be wildcard characters.

In most SQL dialects including MySQL, the wildcard character is '%' to match a sequence of characters, not `*`